# Getting every table data content inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm having some problem with getting my td-content. Some cells contain "-"
and if they, they should have text-align: center.

having some problem with my jquery code especially the if statement, i'm getting always false. need some help!

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#listTable tr td').each(function(){
    var cellText = $(this).text();
    if(cellText == "-") {
        $(this).addClass('textCenter');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `if(cellText.indexOf("-") != -1)` is your answer ;)

Comment: @CodeiSir thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

HTML: A basic table with various content - one of which contains the char "**-**" in the cell.

```
<table border="1" width="400">
  <tr><td>One</td><td>Two</td><td>Three</td></tr>
  <tr><td>One A</td><td>Two-B</td><td>Three C</td></tr>
  <tr><td>One D</td><td>Two E</td><td>Three F</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS: As you likely have already, a simple class

```
.textCenter { text-align: center; }
```

JavaScript: If your requirements are as simple as described, then this will select all of the <td> elements that contain the char "**-**" within.

```
$('td:contains("-")').addClass('textCenter');
```

jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/likestothink/42xqg5bj/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.includes` on a string like so:

```
if (cellText.includes("-")) {
    $(this).addClass('textCenter');
}
```

Comment: I just tried it; `.contains` works in Chrome. Hmm... But you're right! It really should be `.includes`.